# Java runtime polymorphism not working with different parameter types

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading, overriding

I have 3 different class,

```
public class Parent {
    public void add(double a, double b) {
        System.out.println("Parent class add(double double)");
    }

public class Child extends Parent {
    public void add(long a, long b) {
        System.out.println("Child class add(long long)");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String arr[]) {
        Parent parent = new Child();
        parent.add((long)System.currentTimeMillis(), (long)System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

The output should be **Child class add(long long)**, but instead of this, 
it is showing **Parent class add(double double)**

But when I am adding child's class's add method in parent class, it is 
showing correct output. Can anyone please tell me the reason.

Comment: I would suggest to use `@Override` every time when method is overridden

Comment: @Override is a good practice and habit to get into however it does not apply in this case since the code is not actually being overridden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the method signature to be called is chosen [at compile time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12).  The compiler only knows that `parent` is of type `Parent`, so the only compatible signature is `add(double, double)`, because both `long`s can be widened to be `double`s.

The `Child` method `add(long, long)` is an overload, not an override, so `Child` inherits the `add(double, double)` method, and it is called.

If you add the `add(long, long)` method to the `Parent` class, then it will be an exact match and it will be called over the `add(double, double)` method.

Answer (score 2):

You are not `overriding` the methods in the `Child` class. You are `overloading` the inherited methods from the `Parent` class. `Runtime polymorphism` only applies to overridden methods in a subclass and not it's overloaded form.

An explanation of why this happens is as follows :

1. The `Child` class inherits the `public` `add` method that takes two `double` arguments. Even if you can't see it in the code, the child class actually contains a `public` `add` method that takes two `double` arguments.
2. When you define a method called `add` in `Child` that takes two `long` arguments, you are essentially overloading the inherited `add` method that takes two `double` arguments.
3. Since `run-time polymorphism` is only applicable at, well, `runtime`, the compiler does not know at compile time that the `Child` class overloads the `add` method to take two `long` arguments instead. At runtime, the JVM will simply dispatch the call to the inherited `add` method that takes two `double` arguments since that's the method that the `Child` class overrides.

You should always add the `@Override` annotation above a method that you think that you are overriding from a parent class. This has two advantages

1. You know right away when you look at a method that it is overriding a method from the super class.
2. You get a compilation error straight away if the parent class does not contain a method with a similar signature.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access methods of subclasses when using a superclass-reference. The described behaviour is expected, since there is no method `add(long, long)` within `Parent`, but only a method `add(double, double)` (thus, you do not override, but overload `add` within `Child`).

Answer (score 0):

You are overloading not overriding here. So when you run the code you are executing against Parent.add(double,double) and your long arguments are being widened to be doubles.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5